# How to deploy a subsonic application with asp.net MVC

Tags: subsonic

How to deploy the subsonic asp.net mvc application. Do i have to install anything. Please suggest. I am newbie to subsonic.

Comment: Are you currently having issues?  If so can you list them?  It also might help if you include the version of SS you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to install anything, just include the Subsonic dll (name varies depending upon version of SS you are using).  Then only other dependency would be if you are using mysql or entityframework for your db in which case you'd need to include those as well, but when you add Subsonic as a reference to your project these should get added automatically as well.